# Intl PHP extension not working

Tags: php, macos, zend-framework2, intl

I want to use https://github.com/juriansluiman/SlmLocale module in zend framework-2 and need intl extension, I have installed using pecl and it show success. I had added

```
extension=intl.so
```

and restarted my MAMP-Pro, I had tried other links as well: 
http://mynameispagewood.com/web-development/how-to-enable-intl-extension-mamp-osx-10-9-2/
http://codingexplained.com/operating-systems/mac/installing-php-intl-extension-os-x-mavericks
to enable it but its not working.

note: No error while starting apache

Is their any alternate method to enable it?

Any light on the path would be helpful

Thanks

Comment: How are you testing whether or not it's working?

Comment: @TimFountain I suppose phpInfo(), should display information about this extension but it is not. and when i try ( pecl install intl command) it shows already installed.

Comment: Phpinfo will display intl extension if enabled like this :version  1.1.0
ICU version  51.2
ICU Data version  51.2

Answer (score 0):

You will need to ensure that the version of php being called is in the install path for Brew, otherwise it will be picking up the native installed php

Answer (score 0):

The problem can be solved by first checking the php version in the terminal.
The `which php` command will print the `/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.1.8/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin`.

and then check
    echo $PATH
    /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.1.8/bin/php
If this is right, then no need of installing intl extension, restart MAMP PRO, then it should work.